# Rename multiple files by removing filename prefix

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, I have multiple files in a folder where I need to rename those files as the the given pattern.

Example:

Folder : `/Users/Usr1/Documents/FilesFolder` and

File's :

1. `0. a101.employee.txt`
2. `1. a101.department.txt`
3. `2. a101.salary.txt`

[image]

I want to remove the prefix of the file till `a101` and rename to `empoloyee.txt`/`salary.txt`.

**Expected Output**:

[image]

**My try**:

```
import os
path = '/Users/User1/Documents/FilesFolder'
files = os.listdir(path)


for index, file in enumerate(files):
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, file), os.path.join(path,file.removeprefix('a101')))
```

But unable to get expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
import os
import re

path = '/Users/User1/Documents/FilesFolder'
files = os.listdir(path)

p = ".*a101.(.+)"

for file in files:
    m = re.match(p, file)

    if m is not None:
        file_new = m.group(1)

        print(file_new)
```

Comment: Getting `employee.txt.txt`

Comment: @MAK it seems, that the extensions are hidden in your explorer, thats why you are getting `.txt.txt`. If you want to get rid of the extra extension, change pattern to `p = ".*a101.(.+).txt"`

Answer (score 1):

i can suggest you:

```
files = ["0. a101.employee.txt", "1. a101.department.txt" ,"2. a101.salary.txt"]
for index, file in enumerate(files):
    filename = file.split(".")
    print(filename[2]+"."+filename[3])
```

I got the followingoutput:

```
employee.txt
department.txt
salary.txt
```

Comment: File name's are like `0. a101.employee.txt` till `10000. a101.xyz.txt`

Comment: Oh, so i'll edit to do the right job

Answer (score 1):

I think this can solve your problem

```py
import os
import glob

# directory Path
path = "/path/to/dir"
# move to directory
os.chdir(path)

# Getting all files in the directory which contains a101
files = glob.glob("*a101*")

for file in files:
    splitted = file.split('.')
    filename, ext = splitted[-2], splitted[-1]
    new_name = f"{filename}.{ext}"
    os.rename(file, new_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file name is following same pattern with 3 `.` then you can use this for renaming. `removeprefix` is introduced in `python 3.9`.

```py
files = ["0. a101.employee.txt", "1. a101.department.txt" ,"2. a101.salary.txt"]
for file in files:
    print(".".join(file.split(".")[-2:]))
```

output:

```
employee.txt
department.txt
salary.txt
```